# Scale SVG images according to the widest image, keep ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm looking for a way to scale multiple images with a somewhat complicated markup (please advise if you see something that could be changed to achieve this, while maintaining the same functionality).

The idea is that the widest image will set the size of all other images. So when the browser window is shrunken och expanded (which will adjust the container with the blue border) it'll resize all images to the width of said container (the height of all images must remain the same at all times so that no text will look larger than the other).

An outtake of the markup is below, and here's an unfinished **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wewa/2/)**
A visual reference of the look I'm striving for **[HERE](http://jsbin.com/vese/3/)** (this one will not scale as it should but shows how the list of images should look while scaling to the container width).

```
<div class="row center-width">
    <div class="small-12">
        <div class="checkbox clearfix">
            <input id="AlbertoAlessi" type="checkbox" value="Alberto Alessi" name="designers[]">
            <label class="fieldchk" for="AlbertoAlessi"></label>
            <label class="namechk" for="AlbertoAlessi"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/names/DM25_website_orange-03.svg"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox clearfix">
            <input id="RonArad" type="checkbox" value="Ron Arad" name="designers[]">
            <label class="fieldchk" for="RonArad"></label>
            <label class="namechk" for="RonArad"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/names/DM25_website_orange-04.svg"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox clearfix">
            <input id="TimBlanks" type="checkbox" value="TimBlanks" name="designers[]">
            <label class="fieldchk" for="TimBlanks"></label>
            <label class="namechk" for="TimBlanks"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/names/DM25_TIM.svg"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox clearfix">
            <input id="Barnbrook" type="checkbox" value="Jonathan Barnbrook" name="designers[]">
            <label class="fieldchk" for="Barnbrook"></label>
            <label class="namechk" for="Barnbrook"><img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3618143/names/DM25_website_orange-06.svg"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  If you want to expand the width while maintaining the height, which would lead to stretched out characters.  Or if you want to increase the height and width to fill the space, but that would give unnecessary emphasis to shorter names.  SVGs can work with percentage widths/heights which you could use to achieve either.

I got the former to work by adding this to your CSS:

```
.checkbox label.namechk {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

label.namechk svg {
  padding-left: 50px; 
  width: 100%;
}
```

Doesn't give you that vertical centering, but that's as far as I'll go with absolutely positioned elements.

If you want to preserve the shape of the fonts, you may want to investigate kearning/letter spacing which svgs support: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/text-element.html#letter-spacing-kerning